# How to correctly create an Elasticsearch range query of two numbers with potential alphabet prefix?

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I want to perform an elastic search for range between 2 numbers with a wildcard prefix.
Ex:

1. User gives 203 and 899. I want to find all numbers between 203 and 899. BUT the database could have a Character in front of the number like A203 and B899. I want the result to include the range between A203 and B899.

I think Regex i could do [A-Z]?203 but then I am not sure if it can figure out the numerical range of the values that way?
So to sum it up - my table has data such as A20322, B3415, C777, 856, Y888 etc. and I want to be able to find the ranges of those values while ignoring the Character prefix if it exists :
So if I enter C777 and 856, I want to find all numbers between 777 and 856 (ignoring the letter in front of C)..

I know Elastic search has a RangeQuery function but it seems to accept numbers and not regex...
Thanks!

I tried RangeQuery and I don't think its returning the result I want. I tried:
QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("test").gte("[A-Z]?123").lte("[A-Z]?456");

I tried the regex test:

```
[A-B]*3456789[0-9][0-9][0-9]
and it works for A3456789333. BUT when I try to put into elasticsearch query:
{
"query":{
"regexp":{
"name":"[A-B]*3456789[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
}}}
```

And I just get 0 hits when i know i have 3456789123 among other values... Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I tried to create a regexquery:
QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("regexExpression","\\+?*[0-9]345[0-9]");
and the query shows :
value :  "\\+?*[0-9]345[0-9]"
but i still get 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by combining a wildcard query with a range query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "test.keyword": "[A-Z]?*"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "test": {
              "gte": 203,
              "lte": 899
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For the use in the Java SDK:

```java
public class ElasticsearchQueryExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(/* YOUR ELASTIC CLIENT */)) {

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("your_index_name");
            
            BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

            // create the wildcard query
            WildcardQueryBuilder wildcardQuery = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("test.keyword", "[A-Z]?*");
            boolQuery.must(wildcardQuery);

            // create the range query
            RangeQueryBuilder rangeQuery = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("test").gte(203).lte(899);
            boolQuery.must(rangeQuery);

            // add the query
            SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            sourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
            searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

            // send the request
            SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i combine them? I tried:
 QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("test", "[A-Z]?*");
  QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("test").gte("123").lte(456); 
and it seems i only have the "range" part... thanks

Comment: Thank you! - another follow up question for better understanding. I understand the syntax for wildcard regex - in terms of the range gte/lte section, I would need to remove the "A-Z" from the input right? Like if user inputs A248 - 999, I would check for the input if there is a character in prefix, if yes then remove it then create the query as above correct? 
And how does Elasticsearch "know" the values will return a range with or without the Alphabet? Just trust it will be treated as number?

Comment: The only solution you have is the Painless script otherwise, it's not possible.

N.B: If your database is large then painless script needs huge time to be executed as it goes through every document of your database.

Comment: It seems the wildcard is not working correctly - if I do:
QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery("\\+?*" + stringValue); it works (if i ignore +
But if i use WildCareQuery it doesnt seem to work... is there a setting i need to set?